# agents sharing with each other their lists

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I am making a NetLogo model. Each agent has a list of 5 integers (agent-list). On each tick, turtles create link with one other turtle, and share with each other their list.

```
turtles-own [ agent-list ]
.
.
.    
ask turtles [
    create-link-with one-of other turtles
    set agent-list lput agent-list of link-neighbors agent-list
  ]
```

I know the code above doesn't work, how should I fix it?

Comment: After one tick, are you wanting turtles to have an `agent-list` like `[ 1 1 1 1 1 [ 2 2 2 2 2 ] ]` or `[ [ 1 1 1 1 1 ] [ 2 2 2 2 2 ] ]` or `[ 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]` or something different? Can you provide a little more detail?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, I want the last format: [ 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to combine the lists as you've described would probably be `sentence`:

```
turtles-own [ agent-list ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 3 [ 
    set agent-list map [random 10] range 5
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to link-and-share
  ask turtles [
    let target one-of other turtles
    create-link-with target
    set agent-list sentence agent-list [agent-list] of target
    show agent-list
  ]
end
```

However, you'll have do do some tweaking depending on what you're actually looking to do since that means that turtles linking later in the procedure are likely to pull the `agent-list` of turtles that have already modified their own `agent-list`. So, if turtle 0 grabs the `agent-list` of turtle 1, then later turtle 4 grabs the `agent-list` of turtle 0, turtle 4 would have an `agent-list` of 15 integers, not 10, similar to the output below:

```
(turtle 1): [6 1 5 4 7 3 9 8 1 1]
(turtle 0): [9 0 3 3 5 3 9 8 1 1]
(turtle 2): [3 9 8 1 1 9 0 3 3 5 3 9 8 1 1]
```